# Hyperledger Node API: Registration failled

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

When I try to register a new user throw the Node API I get, in the API logs: "Registration of sam failled: identity is alrady register". This is also visible from the CA logs.

However, when I invoque some transaction with that user, I get: "Identity not found in wallet", which is incoherent with the previous logs. Also, if I inspect the API container, there is no ID for sam in the wallet folder.

I would apreciate help! Thaks.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the wallet path, from where it's reading the identity of sam?

Comment: Store path for every wallet is /usr/src/app/wallet in the API container. There is not wallet for Sam there.